# Is there a better IIS 7 bindings dialog?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, windows, bindings

Some of my sites in IIS have 20-30 bindings and the bindings dialog box in IIS 7 is 4 lines, which makes editing bindings a real pain. Are there any replacements/upgrades for the dialog specifically? I realize behind the scenes it is just updating an XML file, but I would prefer not to directly edit the XML file or start writing a separate management application, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything on Google but [this](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/05/16/programmatically-creating-an-iis7-site.aspx) code should be helpful in building a C# Forms App that does it the way that you want - this has the advantage of connecting directly to IIS so it would work for any machine (as opposed to hacking the XML directly).

Comment: Definitely would be better than editing the XML file directly.